# How can I execute Python script in a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping

Here is my Python script:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

myUrl='https://www.youtube.com/user/HolaSoyGerman/about'
uClient = uReq(myUrl)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("h1",{"class":"branded-page-header-title"})

filename="Products2.csv"
f = open(filename,"w")

headers = "Channel Name,Channel Description,Channel Social Media Links\n"

f.write(headers)

channel_name = containers[0].a.text 
print("Channel Name :" + channel_name)

aboutUrl='https://www.youtube.com/user/HolaSoyGerman/about'


uClient1 = uReq(aboutUrl)
page_html1 = uClient1.read()
uClient1.close()

page_soup1 = soup(page_html1, "html.parser")

description_div = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"about-description 
branded-page-box-padding"})
channel_description = description_div[0].pre.text
print("Channel Description :" + channel_description)
f.write(channel_name+ "," +channel_description)
links = page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"channel-links-item"})
for link in links:
social_media = link.a.get("href")
f.write(","+" "+social_media+"\n")
f.close()
```

Here is my index.html code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <form>
 <div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-md-8">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Enter Url</label>
 <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" 
 placeholder="Email">
 </div>
 </div>
 </form> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

I want to write my above mentioned Python script in this index.html and execute it.
I want the user to enter a URL in this input so I can grab that value in my script in place of hard-coded URL. How can I write my Python script in index.html and grab the HTML input value in my Python script as a Python variable?

Comment: Try check http://pyjs.org/ Basically you can transpil your python script into javascript so you can add it into html page

Comment: can u give me a example regarding my code?

Comment: oh, i see u use "open", you will not able to do it in pyjs

Comment: so how can i achieve this? i want html input box value in my python variable

Comment: First of all, you cannot embed python script into html page. Your only option is javascript, because web browsers support only javascript. So, you can rewrite your script into javascript, or trinspil it using pyjs. Also as I mentioned you cannot use "open" in pyjs.

Comment: Another question, where you'd like to execute python script? In your user machine, or in your server?

Comment: Use `django` or place your script in `/cgi-bin` ( and `chmod +x` ) or rewrite your code in `php`.

Comment: You need a Python Web platform run Python code,  such as django or flask.